# Can we use Executor with multiple activities?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am collecting data from different activity and sending to the server periodically, also if the user is in offline mode am using Sqlite to save data and again sending that whenever the internet available,

I have to schedule this transmission from many activities

1. which is the best for my requirement asyncTask or IntentService ?
2. I have to divide the data as chunks if huge data present in Sqlite, please suggest some algorithms to do this.

Comment: what happens if i start a network operation to send sqlite data to server and deleting it after i getting the successful response from the server, will this successfully executes even after started activity killed ? or will it causes any context leak ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent service is the best method, also it avoids context leak !

Answer (score 0):

1.asyncTask is used  lock the ui thread and ruining for long time process such as connect the web server.[more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2.IntentService is one kind of service it use handle asynchronous requests.[more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)
you can see this tutorial for send data to web server [sync](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)

Comment: please check my comments .!

Comment: for asynctask  .........Asynctask have a one override method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29  (onPostExecute(Result)) through this method you can change the activity ui or can finish the activity .

Comment: at first you read asynctask life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html